# Pygame fullscreen display doesn't work on TV

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pygame, fullscreen, television

I'm using Pygame Screen to show a fullscreen image... It works on my monitor, but when I connect the raspberry to TV and run the code, it's not completely fullscreen and little bit smaller.

Here is the code I use:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN) 
displayRes = pygame.display.get_surface()
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
pic = pygame.image.load("standard.jpg")
screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(pic, (int(displayRes.get_width()), int(displayRes.get_height()))), (0, 0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Edit: Actually pygame.display.get_surface() returns the wrong numbers of width and height. When I'm using these numbers for OMXPlayer, it doesn't display in fullscreen, too.

Comment: One thing to check is the Overscan (or underscan) settings of your TV - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan

Answer (score 0):

@Kingsley comment gave me the idea to turn the Overscan in Raspbian off and now it works great on TV and monitor.

To do that:
Open Terminal ~> Type sudo raspi-config ~> Advanced Option ~> Overscan ~> Switch to NO ~> Reboot your Raspberry!